# Prevent from property realoading from DB in View Model in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a concept question i am having situation like this: 
I have MainWindow, on this windows there are button that switch sub view from one to another. Now on sub view number 1 I am getting some information from data base, I am passing that information to sub view number 2 using constructor something like:

```
    public DataParsingViewModel(List<ProcessedEventsData> preprocessedEvents)
    {
        Service = new EventService();

        if (this.preprocessedEvents == null  || (preprocessedEvents.Count != this.preprocessedEvents.Count))
        {
            this.preprocessedEvents = preprocessedEvents;

            PopulateAxmFilter();
            PopulateSrcChannelFilter();
            PopulateTimestampsFilter();
            PopulateEventCodeFilter();
        }

        foreach (ProcessedEventsData preprocessedEvent in preprocessedEvents)
        {
            PreprocessedEvents.Add(preprocessedEvent);
        }
    }
```

And call from main window view model:

```
    private void SetDataParsingView()
    {
        List<ProcessedEventsData> eventList = preprocessingViewModel.Events.ToList();
        ContentControlDataContext = eventList.Any() ? new DataParsingViewModel(preprocessingViewModel.Events.ToList()) : new DataParsingViewModel();
    }
```

Now I am having situation that if i press sub view number 2, each time property is reloading. Can it be done so it would reload only if preprocessedEvents change if first sub view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just save your `eventList` in a property or field instead of a local variable and only fill it from the database if it does not already exist.

```
private List<ProcessedEventsData> eventList;

private void SetDataParsingView()
{
    if(this.eventList == null)
    {
        this.eventList = preprocessingViewModel.Events.ToList();
    }

    ContentControlDataContext = eventList.Any() ? new DataParsingViewModel(preprocessingViewModel.Events.ToList()) : new DataParsingViewModel();
}
```